# Labels Turned on at Close Zoom Level

Tags: kml

I've searched the various forums and can't find this question asked.  If it has, please point me to it.

I'm generating a .KML file with lots of point data in a 400 mile area.  When the file is opened, points labels are shown which makes it very busy.

What I'd like is for the file to open with only the points and no labels.  Then when the users zooms in to let's say 20 miles, the labels are shown.

I have control over the generation of the KML file, so I can add any additional "parameters" that I need to accomplish this effect.

I'd appreciate someone pointing me to the best method to do this.

Thanks,

MEG

Answer (score 2):

Add each of your points *twice* to your KML file and place them in different [Regions](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/regions). In the outer region, you can hide the labels via [this technique](https://developers.google.com/kml/faq#hidelabel).

Comment: If KML has lots of points then you may want to separate the set of points into separate KML files then add NetworkLinks to the root KML file with Regions defined on the NetworkLinks so only the appropriate set is loaded depending on the zoom level. Getting the Regions correct is often trial and error.